# how to add has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first question, ive looking for an question similar but hadnt found it, i'm starting learning ruby on rails and i followed a course that said for creating foreing keys with has_many

i create my class Band by.

```
rails g model Band name:string website:string email:string
```

and i also have created my class Genres in the same way
this orders generate classes like

```
class Band < ActiveRecord:Base
end
```

so i edit my file Band.rb like this

```
class Band < ActiveRecord:Base
    has_many :Genres
end
```

save changes (Ctrl+S) and when i try to create a new object o class Band

```
a = Band.new
```

a hasnt the genres atribut

Comment: Need to see more code.  Does your Genres has the belongs_to association with Band?  What error are you receiving?

Comment: Have you created the database with `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `band.rb` file to:

```
class Band < ActiveRecord:Base
    has_many :genres
end
```

reload, and everything should be fine since then.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that in Your Genre model you have

```
belongs_to :band
```

Also in you Band model lowercase you has_many relationship like so

```
has_many :genres
```

since a genre belongs to a band you need to have a band_id in you genres table which will point to the band that genre belongs to.

then you can easily find the band the genres for a band.In you controller you can find a band

```
@band = Band.find(params[:id])
```

and to check the genre that was set before you can do

```
@genre = @band.genres
```

this will give you the correct genres for that band .

However this seems more like a situation where a band has_many :genres and a genre has_many :bands.In this case you may want to use a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.You can find more details for associations in the rails guides here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

If you go with the has_and_belongs_to_many relationships you need to create a separate table where each genre and band will point to each other so you can associate them easily

Answer (score 0):

the new method will not create the actual record in the database, you have to call save on the instance. To create associate genre, you can call create_genre on the already exists Band instance.